# C++ For Loop Won't Run

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I'm beginning to learn c++ with the free online codecademy course, and I'm not sure if it's a bug with their IDE or an error in my code.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    int main() {

      for (int i = 0; i > 0; i--) {
          std::cout << i << " bottles of beer on the wall\n";
          std::cout << i << " bottles of beer\n.";
          std::cout << "take one down and guzzle it down\n";
          std::cout << i - 1 << " bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n";
      }

    }
```

This is supposed to loop those strings until the number gets down to 1. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The compiler is convinced `i > 0` is false and thus doesn't even enter the loop. What is the initial value of `i`?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i > 0; i--) {` Think about this one a bit more.

Comment: Your code does exactly what you think it should, except `i` is never greater than 0, so the loop never runs

Comment: You set `i` to `0`.  Since it is `0`, what is the result of `i > 0`?

Comment: how many times can you substract 1 from 0 before it gets 0 ?

Comment: The tune is **99** bottle of beer on the wall. Isn't that a strong indicator the value *99* should appear at least once.... *somewhere* ?

Comment: Can you confirm that if you take the exact code you have shown in your (edited) question, you still get no output?  It works for me.

Comment: After redoing the whole thing from scratch it turns out that somewhere in the original that I made in codeacedemy, I messed up the syntax of whatever code they provided me. Thank you for the quick answers.

Comment: please dont fix your code in the question. If you found a solution you can post an answer. In its current state your question is confusion and you can delete it as well. Unless you still get no output for this code....which would be really strange ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `i` is never bigger than 0.

I think that you meant to write `int i = 10;`

Comment: Sorry, I copied it over wrong. How can I edit this?

Comment: @Secksee There should be a little grey "edit" button underneath your question's text.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <string>

    int main() {

      for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
          std::cout << i << " bottles of beer on the wall\n";
          std::cout << i << " bottles of beer\n.";
          std::cout << "take one down and guzzle it down\n";
          std::cout << i - 1 << " bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n";
      }

    }
```

I am not sure what your code is supposed to loop through. but this will run 10 times. you say you have a string. so try to get a variable to assign to a function string.length() to get the length assigned to `i` and then the loop will run as many times as the number of characters in the string. 
the above code will run 10 times though

Comment: This program seems to be intended to print the [99 bottles of beer on the wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/99_Bottles_of_Beer) song. So I would assume the loop is intended to start at 99.